Poisson structure which is non-degenerate on the smooth locus
I hope this is not a silly question. I recently started studying Poisson structures on algebraic varieties.
Here is my question: Let $X$ be an algebraic variety, possibly not smooth. If $X$ is even dimension, Cohen-Macaulay and the singular locus has codimension at least 2 (i.e., $X$ is normal), does there exist a Poisson structure on $X$ that is non-degenerate on the smooth locus of $X$?
I think that there is a similar statement in the page 2 of paper of E. Etingof and T. Schedler. I really appreciate any of your comments in advance!

In the paper you mention, $X$ is a surface. Are you assuming that? Otherwise the answer is obviously no, e.g. if $\dim X$ is odd.

Thanks abx! I am considering general X, not only a surface. In addition, I think that I can add the assumption that $\mathrm{dim}\ X$ is even. Does this make sense? Thank you for pointing out this!

It is already false if $X$ is a smooth projective surface: your assumption implies that $X$ has trivial canonical bundle.

I understand. In fact, my question might have so generous condition since I am considering affine, reduced, irreducible and normal variety. I really appreciate your kind answers, abx!

Note that Etingof and Schindler consider surfaces which are complete intersections in affine space — in that case the canonical bundle is trivial, so there is indeed a nondegenerate Poisson structure on the smooth locus. But this is a very particular case.

I see, the important thing is complete intersection, not Cohen-Macaulay. Your answers are very helpful to me. I really appreciate your answers!
